# In welchen Fällen setzt man vor dem vergleichenden "als" und "wie" ein Komma?

Tags: spelling, comma, comparison

Es geht um die vergleichenden Wörtern *als* und *wie*. Es ist klar, dass im folgenden Satz kein Komma zu setzen ist:

> Anna ist älter als Peter.

Aber wie ist es beim nächsten Beispiel?

> Anna ist beim Laufen schneller(,) als Peter im letzten Jahr war.

Muss oder darf man hier den Beistrich setzen? Mit welcher Begründung?

Comment: +1 weil ich mich das selbst schon oft gefragt habe und immer zu faul zum nachschlagen war.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Das wird in [Regel 112](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/komma#K112) des Duden beschrieben:

> Wenn die vergleichenden Konjunktionen „als" oder „wie" nur Wörter oder Wortgruppen verbinden (also keine Nebensätze einleiten), setzt man kein Komma <§ 74 E3>. (Vgl. auch Regel 116.)
>
> Die Wunde heilte besser als erwartet.
>
> (Aber: Die Wunde heilte besser, als wir erwartet hatten.)

Alles andere fällt laut Regel 113 unter [Regel 100](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/komma#K100):

> Das Komma steht bei Aufzählungen, zwischen gleichrangigen Wörtern und Wortgruppen, wenn sie nicht durch Wörter wie „und" oder „oder" (vgl. Regel 111 und Regel 113) verbunden sind <§ 71 (2) und 72>.

Ich hoffe, ich interpretiere jetzt richtig, dass in Deinem Beispiel daher ein Komma gesetzt werden muss.