# Komma vor »wie« bei Anführung eines Beispiels

Tags: comma

Die Frage bezieht sich auf den [vorliegenden Post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1738/in-welchen-f%C3%A4llen-setzt-man-vor-dem-vergleichenden-als-und-wie-ein-komma). Ich bin mir nicht ganz sicher, ob ich die Kommasetzung von »wie« richtig verstanden und in meinem Beispiel angewendet habe. Ich würde mich über eine kurze Korrektur oder Erklärung freuen.

> Komplexe Modelle, wie Polynome höherer Ordnung, können sich flexibler …

oder

> Komplexe Modelle wie Polynome höherer Ordnung können sich flexibler …

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Frage, auf die du verlinkt hast, behandelt Vergleiche (*»A ist gleich groß **wie** B«*). In deinem Satz liegt aber kein Vergleich vor, hier handelt es sich um eine nachgestellte Erläuterung.

Hier gilt:

Steht die Erläuterung am Ende des Satzes, muss sie mit einem Komma abgetrennt werden:

> **richtig:**
>   Das gilt auch für komplexe Modelle, wie Polynome höherer Ordnung.
>
> **falsch:**
>   Das gilt auch für komplexe Modelle wie Polynome höherer Ordnung.

Steht sie Erläuterung im Inneren des Satzes, so wie in deinem Beispiel, ist die Setzung des Kommas erlaubt, aber nicht zwingend vorgeschrieben:

Also:

> **erlaubt:**
>   Komplexe Modelle, wie Polynome höherer Ordnung, können sich flexibler entfalten.
>
> **erlaubt:**
>   Komplexe Modelle wie Polynome höherer Ordnung können sich flexibler entfalten.

Als Entscheidungshilfe gibt es eine Empfehlung:

- Erläuterungen, die nicht am Satzende stehen, sollte man immer dann in Kommas einschließen, wenn der Satz auch ohne die Erläuterung einen Sinn ergibt.

Der Satz

> Komplexe Modelle können sich flexibler entfalten.

ergibt einen Sinn. Daher:

> **empfohlen:**
>   Komplexe Modelle, wie Polynome höherer Ordnung, können sich flexibler entfalten.
>
> **nicht empfohlen, aber trotzdem erlaubt:**
>   Komplexe Modelle wie Polynome höherer Ordnung können sich flexibler entfalten.

Comment: Eine super Antwort, die mir wirklich weiter hilft. Vielen dank für die zusätzliche Empfehlungshilfe

Comment: @Vala Man muss auch beachten, dass die nicht empfohlene Variante in diesem Fall zweideutig ist, da hier das "wie" auch als "und" interpretiert werden kann. Das würde den Sinn des Satzes aber völlig verändern.

Comment: @IQV: »Sowie« kann als »und« interpretiert werden, »wie« wohl kaum. Kannst du Beispiele vorbringen, die deine These belegen würden?